# How to use ResultSet: absolute(int row) in java and dispaly retrieved rows in tabular format through jsp using jstl

Tags: java, jsp, cursor, resultset

I want to retrieve some specific rows from ResultSet by using **absolute(int row) method**.I have retrieved all the rows in tabular format by following code:

```
public String[][] reference() {

        String a[][]=new String[46][2];
        int i=0;
        try
            { 
              con = getConnection();
              stmt = con.createStatement(rs.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,rs.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
              String sql="select logtime,beam_current from INDUS2_BDS.dbo.DCCT where logtime between '2014-10-10 07:17:00' and '2014-10-10 08:46:00'"+
              "and (beam_current like '%9.96' or beam_current like '%9.97' or beam_current like '%9.98' or  beam_current like '%9.99'  or beam_current like '%0' or beam_current like '%_0.01' or beam_current like '%_0.02' or beam_current like '%_0.03' or beam_current like '%_0.04' or beam_current like '%_0.05' or beam_current like '%_0.06')";
              stmt.executeQuery(sql);
              rs = stmt.getResultSet();

              while(rs.next()) 
              {

                      for(int j=0; j<2; j++)

                        {
                            a[i][j] = rs.getString(j+1);

                        }

                        i++;
                  }
           }

         catch( Exception e )
            {
                System.out.println("\nException "+e);
            }
            finally
            {
                closeConnection(stmt, rs, con);
            }
        return a;
```

Now I only want to retrieve only 3,4,11,13,23,27,28 rows in-spite of all.How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `int rowCounter=0;` before the `while` and increase it in the end of the `while` body.

Add a check `if (rowCounter==3 || rowCounter==4 ...) { //do your logic}`

Comment: How to print that Resulset absolute() value on browser i.e when I do          if (rowCounter==3 || rowCounter==4 ...) {rs.absolute(3);rs.absolute(4)}return rs  , then I get **SQLServerResultSet:1** as output not that particular row

Comment: I'm not able to print the rows.